# How do I create a brand new hive file from a reg file?

Tags: windows, registry

I have a `.dbreg` file that contains a textual representation of a bunch of registry entries. How do I convert that into a `.hiv` file without having to load it into my machine's registry?

I'm kind of creating a package that is run in a sort of fake Windows environment (kind of like Wine), and it wants a bunch of `.hiv` files. Merging the text registry entries into an existing `.hiv` file that's sitting in some random location (i.e. not the main system one) would also be an option.

The `reg` utility doesn't really seem to have a way to work with an arbitrary `.hiv` file, aside from the `load`, and `save` commands, which seem to be just about creating and restoring backups.

There must be a way to do this.

**Edit:** I had a misconception about what `reg load` does. It basically 'mounts' (in Unix parlance) a hive file into the existing registry database at a specific point in the key hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have to use a trick to create an empty hiv file. This MSDN blog entry contains a [PowerShell script that creates an empty regsitry hive file](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sergey_babkins_blog/2014/11/10/how-to-create-a-brand-new-registry-hive/). Then you can use `reg load` (which basically 'mounts' a hive file into the existing registry key hierarchy) and `reg import` to import the dbreg file into it, then `reg unload`.